# Factory reset on a laptop that has Windows 8.1 OEM and was downgraded to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, oem, downgrade

I have a laptop that originally came with Windows 8.1 and then I downgraded it to Windows 7.

I need to do a Factory reset on it but want to keep Windows 7.... Should I go through the Recovery manager or will that put it back to Windows 8??

Would the situation be different if the manufacturer was the one who downgraded it through the customization options when ordering the laptop??

Comment: If you downgraded it to W7, the recovery partition will put W8 back on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the one who downgraded it to Windows 7, then doing a factory reset will bring back Windows 8 since Windows 8 will be the Operating System on the recovery partition as @Moab commented. The only solution in this case is to clean install Windows 7.

If the manufacturer downgraded to Windows 7, then there is an equal chance of the recovery partition having either Windows 7 or Windows 8.